# Stop moving a label when another label found in the same direction

Tags: c#, label, drag

I have many labels on a picturebox. I want to move a label with respect to cursor, but label should stop moving when there is another label in the moving direction

Here is my code

```
void lbl_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            lblCutPaste = sender as Control;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
    }

    void lbl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            activeControl = sender as Control;
            previousLocation = e.Location;
            //  preloc = activeControl.Location;
            Cursor = Cursors.Hand;



        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
    }

    void lbl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            bool isCollide = false;
            if (activeControl == null || activeControl != sender)
                return;
            var location = activeControl.Location;
            location.Offset(e.Location.X - previousLocation.X, e.Location.Y - previousLocation.Y);

            if (location.X >= 0 && location.X <= activeControl.Parent.Width - activeControl.Width && location.Y >= 0 && location.Y <= activeControl.Parent.Height - activeControl.Height)
            {
                activeControl.Location = location;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
    }

    void lbl_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
       activeControl = null;
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;

    }
```

Comment: in the direction or overlapping?

Comment: Do have a look at [Rectangle.Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y10fyck0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: THANKS TaW but i already gone through it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example; you will have to adapt your code after studying it. It shouldn't be hard to pull out the lambda into your events.

It first creates 20 `Labels` and add them onto a `PictureBox`. It hooks up each `Label` with three events. It colors the active `Label` while it is being dragged.

Each `Label` is also added to a class level `List<T>` so we can easily do the check we need. The check is using LINQ to count all overlapping labels.

It makes use of the `Rectangle.IntersectsWith` and `Point.Subtract` methods ..

```
List<Label> myLabels = new List<Label>();
Label movingLabel = null;
Point mDown = Point.Empty;

private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random R = new Random(8);
    Size sz = pictureBox1.ClientSize;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Label lbl = new Label() {Text = "L " + i};
        lbl.Location = new Point(R.Next(sz.Width), R.Next(sz.Height));
        lbl.Parent = pictureBox1;
        myLabels.Add(lbl);

        lbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

        lbl.MouseDown += (ss, ee) =>
            {
                movingLabel = lbl;
                lbl.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
                mDown = ee.Location;  
            };

        lbl.MouseMove += (ss, ee) =>
            {
                if (ee.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                {
                   Point nLoc = Point.Subtract(lbl.Location, 
                                      new Size(mDown.X - ee.X, mDown.Y - ee.Y));
                   Rectangle rlbNew = new Rectangle(nLoc, lbl.Size);
                   var overlapped = myLabels.Where(x => x != lbl && 
                              rlbNew.IntersectsWith(new Rectangle(x.Location, x.Size)));
                   if (overlapped.Count() == 0) lbl.Location = nLoc;
                }
            };

        lbl.MouseUp += (ss, ee) =>
            {
                movingLabel = null;
                lbl.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            };
    }
}
```

Note that I didn't care whether the created `Labels` overlap, so some do and as they do can't be moved apart unless you keep dragging until reaches a 'legal' one; then it will jump over the overlapped label and to the new position..

If you wanted you could code logic to allow overlapping while moving, make the backcolor red to show that this is not ok and have it jump back on `MouseUp` if it still overlaps. You will need to store the original position for this.. But dragging to a legal position as it is may well be good enough, imo..

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you It's working thanks

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains us both a little reputation..

Comment: Hello TaW can u explain me when two label is overlapped then how do i move

Comment: Actually I found that if you keep dragging it will jump to the new position once it has reached a 'legal' one. See my update!